# Is it possible to track user movement in Apple watch?

Tags: swift, apple-watch, core-motion

I need to build a watch app that **tracks the user movement**, so I need to use **CoreMotion**.

I searched about this feature in watch and I didn't find any useful tutorial.

my question is:

is it possible to record CoreMotion data in Apple watch and then share it on a server somewhere?